# Google Maps API v3 marker coordinates

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Maps API v3 in my asp content page. I have got a marker in my map, and I need to save the markers coordinates in database. In the .aspx folder the markers coordinates I can show in a `<div id="indo"><div>`. How can I get the marker coordinates in my .aspx.cs file?
[Google example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html)

My code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Dragable Marker Address" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TesztMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TesztContentPage2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Google1.TesztContentPage2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function geocodePosition(pos) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: pos
        }, function (responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
            } else {
                updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
            }
        });
    }

    function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
        document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: 'Point A',
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });

        // Update current position info.
        updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
        geocodePosition(latLng);

        // Add dragging event listeners.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
            updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
            updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
            updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });
    }

    // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  #mapCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
  #infoPanel {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

```
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
    <div id="infoPanel">
        <b>Marker status:</b>
        <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
        <b>Current position:</b>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <b>Closest matching address:</b>
        <div id="address"></div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddeninputname" value="" runat="server"/>
```

then in the javascript code you save the coordinates in it:

```
document.getElementById('hiddeninputname').value = yourcoordinates;
```

and then you can access your hidden input from the code behind by using:

```
hiddeninputname.Value;
```

NOTE: If you have multiple coordinates you can save them in a string separated by a '_' or a chatracter of your choice. and then in the code behind you can extract them from the string

**EDIT** 
If you want to set the text directly from javascript you can place a label in your div

```
<label id="LabelId"></label>
```

and set its text to whatever you want

```
document.getElementById('labelId').InnerHTML = 'Coordinate Text Goes Here';
```

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it killed the googlemaps api javascript function. Any idea to get out text by the div element?

Comment: document.getElementById('label').value = ... is vorked for me